# Understanding $X_n = \big\{ \text{lattices } Λ < \Bbb R^n: \operatorname{covol} Λ = 1\big\} \cong SL(n, \Bbb Z) \setminus SL(n, \Bbb R)$

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, lattices-in-lie-groups

$X_n = \big\{ \text{lattices } Λ < \Bbb R^n: \operatorname{covol} Λ = 1\big\} \cong SL(n, \Bbb Z) / \operatorname{SL}(n, \Bbb R)$, with isomorphism given by: $\Bbb Zv_1 + \Bbb Zv_2 + \cdots + \Bbb Zv_n \mapsto SL(n, \Bbb Z)(v_1, \ldots , v_n)^T$

> Please help me understand why this is true?

From what I understand, the LHS of the map:  $\Bbb Zv_1 + \Bbb Zv_2 + \cdots + \Bbb Zv_n$ represents the lattice. The RHS of the map: $SL(n, \Bbb Z)(v_1, \ldots , v_n)^T$ is the special linear group over the integers? But what is this: $(v_1, \ldots , v_n)^T?$

Comment: Every matrix in $\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ gives a lattice of covolume 1 spanned by its vectors; two matrices induce the same lattice if and only if they are equal up to an integer change of coordinates.

Comment: $(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ is the $n\times n$ matrix whose rows (or maybe columns?) are $v_1,\dots,v_n$, and the $T$ is transpose. The righthand side is describing a coset inside SL(n,$\mathbb R$), generated by the matrix given by $v_1,\dots,v_n$.

Comment: It might be useful to include a definition of [covol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(group)#Dividing_space_according_to_a_lattice). Furthermore, what is $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$ minus $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})$. It would seem that a set minus a superset would be the empty set. Do you mean $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})/\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$?